# Extra space between sentences?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, ios-app

I know this is a minor, but seems there is extra space between sentences on the settings page of the iOS app:

> [image: space?]

- App Version: 1.6.3.4
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will double space after sentences 'til the day I die.  But since it matters to you, I'll change it.

Answer (score 2):

SE settings on Android lack such a notice, although it could be buried in a sub-setting page somewhere.

Double spacing between sentences used to be the norm. The Web has pretty much destroyed this old norm, because consecutive spaces and even line feeds are auto-collapsed into a single space. This effect can be bypassed by the use of specific markup features, but for the most part people just accept it as a new norm.

Perhaps our iOS programmer simply felt that using the double spacing here enhanced clarity.  I.e., it is not an error but a choice. (Some of us old-timers still prefer the old style, even if it is a pain to do on the Web.)

Comment: IMO in those cases line break would work fine.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Double spacing is fine on a typewriter. I don't think it was ever the norm in properly typeset books. A space and a half, perhaps.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen but this is neither a typewriter nor a book, it's a smartphone app.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen: Actually, the norm for books often used to be *more* than double an inter-word space. See this ELU answer by ShreevatsaR: [How many spaces should come after a period/full stop?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/2602/77227) "CMoS 1911 still recommends a 3-em space between words and an em-quad between sentences" A [3-em space](http://www.belltype.com/AboutTypeLetterandLineSpacing.html) is a third of an em; the reported CMoS 1911 guideline therefore makes sentence spacing three times as wide as inter-word spacing.