# Possible double space in the message for already voted for close posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, grammar

> [image: no options]

- App Version: 1.6.4
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)

Comment: Related [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290089/339911)