# Extra space in the "select a browser" message for iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, grammar

If you tap on some image or another link that cannot be opened in the app, and default browser is not set yet you will see a message:

> [image: select a browser]

Seems there is an extra space between sentences. This is popular bug in iOS app.

Related: [Extra space between sentences?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290089/339911)

- App Version: 1.6.5.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291610/possible-double-space-in-the-message-for-already-voted-for-close-posts (aka this is everywhere.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I began to forget the bugs that I found here.

Comment: Well, not sure each should get its own bug report, but not sure enough to close as dupe either. Oh well. :-)

Comment: Honestly, the fact that the next sentence ends in a preposition is more upsetting.